# Retrive msi error code and message in custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a custom action that reports installation failures in WIX project. It is defined like below:

```
<CustomAction Id="ReportError" DllEntry="ReportError" BinaryKey="Actions.dll" Return="check" Execute="immediate" />
...
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ReportError" OnExit="error">NOT Installed</Custom>
  ...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Is it possible to get msi error code and message inside `ReportError` code?

E.g. I can see error like `Error 1327. Invalid Drive: E:\` in the msi log file. How can I retrieve error code **1327** and error message **Invalid Drive: E:\**?

Comment: Some background could be useful. Errors are reported on the standard ErrorDialog, so it's not clear why you need the error in a custom action that reports them. The other issue is that some are not available until the install has finished, returned (for example) in the msiexec exit code. Other errors are detected before your custom action will ever see them because the install won't even proceed.

Comment: The goal is to automate error reporting. So it is ok if we are not able to use some error information. As an option we could analyze exit codes from bootstrapper and process full logs.

Comment: not clear : so msi is not installed and error in log only?

Comment: @user1005462, correct. This question is about installation failure case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about get error text and code but you can show your own error text on any failures:
do like that sample:

```
<CustomAction Id='AddComponent' Property='Component' Value='"!(wix.exeLocation)\sys-or-your.exe" /norestart /quiet' Execute='immediate'/>
<CustomAction Id="Component" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" BinaryKey="WixCA" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="Error" Error="Sys or your Component not added."/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="AddComponent" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="Component" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="Error" OnExit="error">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

or if action.dll is your own you can do some part there and then show diff. error per codes etc;
[Display end-user message in case of an error in custom action in MSI with Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779237/display-end-user-message-in-case-of-an-error-in-custom-action-in-msi-with-wix?rq=3)